# What is the maximum number of rows that can be inserted in a table in oracle?

Tags: oracle

What is the maximum number of rows that can be inserted in a table in oracle?
Does it depends upon columns or tablespace for that table...

Comment: first, you must do some research

Comment: Take a look a the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/physical-database-limits.htm#REFRN0042.  Needless to say, it's a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of the blocks, perhaps [this link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:707430700346624722) can help you find what you are looking for.